# Usage of qtip module in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, qtip, qtip2

How can I add a qtip to a link using the qtip module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip

Answer (score 3):

Hope it helps someone.
Create an instance of qtip from admin/config/user-interface/qtip with any machine name say qtip_default.
Add a span or div after the link, which will contain information about the qtip.

```
<a class='qtip-link'>Shown Link</a>
<span class="qtip-tooltip" data-qtip-title="Title of tooltip" data-qtip-instance="qtip_default">Text of the tooltip</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but you need to put some text in the a tag, like <a class='qtip-link'> ? </a>